# MySQL: Merge two tables (same schema) and create a new one - SINGLE QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, centos

I have two tables with exactly the same schema.

I would like to have a 3rd table, containing all the data of these two tables combined.

How can I do this with an INSERT INTO query (single query doing this)?

I know I can do this with: `INSERT INTO`name_of_new_table`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM`name_of_old_table but then I would need to do it twice. I am seeking to doing this with a SINGLE query.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the table schema using `SHOW CREATE TABLE old_table_1 \G`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT * FROM old_table_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM old_table_2
```

Removed your `DISTINCT`, as `UNION` has an implied `DISTINCT` (`UNION ALL` does not have this). This will only work if the tables are identical in column count and have similar column type, however. Then again, it sounds like that's your situation.

Comment: if the coloumn X in T1 is varchar-128 and in the T2 varchar-126, does this mean it wouldn't work?

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure. I've not had that issue. The documentation says they have to be similar data types (not identical like I said), so it would probably work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, if I may, can I ask you how to avoid the issue of Primary key issue caused by union? I stops the query because of similar primary keys in both tables. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil Is it an identity value, or do the primary keys have some sort of meaning (a meaningful ID, or just an IDENTITY(1,1)?)

Comment: It is the ID column which is INT auto_inc. I found the solution by typing all the column names. Thank you very much for your help.